# How to dump both HTTP request and response in golang

Tags: go, gorilla

I'm using gorilla web tool kit. There's a [LoggingHandler](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/handlers#LoggingHandler) available in the handler package, however it can only log the request data via the handler.

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("This is a catch-all route"))
})
// This can only log the request, how can we log the response?
loggedRouter := handlers.LoggingHandler(os.Stdout, r) 
http.ListenAndServe(":1123", loggedRouter)
```

[httputil](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpRequest) has the same feature available via DumpRequest(). In my case client is a browser, and I'm looking for a handler approach to log the response rather than logging it inside each and every handler.

Comment: You can wrap the `http.ResponseWriter` - doing something like https://godoc.org/github.com/zenazn/goji/web/mutil#WrapWriter - and then write what you want from within your own `WriteHeader` or `Write` method.